# React App deployed on production (Digital Ocean) is not loading on browser

Tags: reactjs, nginx, digital-ocean, production-environment

I have a react app using node api deployed on Digital Ocean.Its using Nginx  webserver.
I can check the status of my api and serve as online using pm2, but on going to my url on browser, m getting "Welcome to Nginx", instead of my react app frontend.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the desired server blocks changes in Nginx in both sites-available and sites-enabled folder.

Both the folders resides in /etc/nginx/

Comment: i have server blocks in sites-available but pls guide what needs to be updated in sites-enabled folder

Comment: Sites-enabled will have the exact same server block as in sites-available. You basically need to copy and paste server block from sites-available to sites-enabled